# how to only insert records into table 2 when field in table 1 is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, insert

Im using sql server and need to insert into a table based on multiple criteria. i know how to do this part. however, the table im pulling from, called accnt, has an "imported" column that either is blank or has an x in it. I only want to insert the records from accnt into table 2, called quick, if the imported column is empty aka its value is ''. the code below is what I have tried, but it doesnt work. the insert statement without trying to tell it to only insert where imported = '' works fine

```
IF accnt.imported = ''
then (
   INSERT INTO quick (date, num, name, account, amount) 
   SELECT invdate,
   case when accnt.accno < '7000' then code else invno end
   , ven, accno, amnt from accnt 
)
```

I also tried:

```
WHEN accnt.imported = ''
INSERT INTO quick (date, num, name, account, amount)
SELECT invdate,
case when accnt.accno < '7000' then code else invno end
, ven, accno, amnt from accnt
```

how do i get this concept to work?

Comment: Are you sure `imported` has an empty string?  Maybe it's `null` you want to be checking against? `if accnt.imported is null`...

Comment: why not both? `IF ISNULL(accnt.imported,'') = ''`

Comment: yes, its definitely an empty string

Comment: This means you have the table `accnt` and this contains many rows. You just want to insert all rows from accnt where a specific field is not empty? Right?

Comment: no, only some of the rows are being inserted from accnt to quick, and there is a criteria for which field quick.num pulls from. and i only want to take the rows where accnt.imported is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following not suffice?

```
INSERT INTO quick (date, num, name, account, amount) 
SELECT invdate,
case when accnt.accno < '7000' then code else invno end
, ven, accno, amnt 
FROM accnt
WHERE ISNULL(accnt.imported, '') = ''
```

Comment: If he just want to import those rows who were empty. Yes. But the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: yes this worked, thank you, i cant believe i didnt think of that